# Referencing a class programatically in PHP

Tags: php, class-reference

I receive an object during some process and this object needs to figure out its coloring scheme.
For example, I have a coloring scheme that is stored like this:

```
class FirstScheme {
    public static $COLORS = array('1' => 'green', '2' => 'red', ...);
}
class SecondScheme {
    public static $COLORS = array('1' => 'red', '2' => 'green', ...);
}
```

I know all the coloring schemes names in advance; they can only change when the code changes.
But the coloring scheme to be used for each object needs to be determined at run-time by matching the attribute of this object.

And here I don't know what to do. In **python** I would define a dict holding the mappings of color schemes to names like this:

```
d = {'attr_value1': FirstScheme, 'attr_value2': SecondScheme, 'attr_value3': FirstScheme, ...}
```

And then just access the "COLORS" variable, because every class should have it. But in **PHP** there is not way to reference a class in a such way, so what is the right way to do it?
Note that more than one attribute can map to the same coloring scheme.

Comment: What if you pass objects, not classes? Static methods/properties are usually considered as a bad practice. In the case of objects - you would have a single class `ColorScheme` and instantiate it with different schemes.

Comment: Why? I don't understand why I need an object when my coloring schemes are pre-determined. I don't need to instantiate them, I know them in advance.

Comment: how the fact that they are predetermined changes the fact that solution with statics sucks? Create a builder that creates various color schemes by request and tie your classes by interfaces, not by hardcoded class and property names

Comment: @dragoon `Coloring scheme is need to be determined at run-time by matching the attribute of this object` Can you explain further?

Comment: @hek2mgl Sure, I know all possible coloring schemes, but I might add more in the future. Each incoming object has some attribute, which allows to unambiguously map in to one of the schemes.

Comment: Still don't get it. Don't make it too complicated. Btw, is my answer already ok for you? (it got 2 upvotes). Is something missing?

Comment: @hek2mgl I added a comment to your answer on the part I don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by `mapping` in `run-time` ? What do you expect your output to be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *every class* should have the colors, define the interface that allows to get them:

```
interface ColorsProvider {
    function getColors();
}
class FirstScheme implements ColorsProvider {
    public static COLORS = array('1' => 'green', '2' => 'red', ...);

    public function getColors() {
        return self::COLORS;
    }
}
class SecondScheme implements ColorsProvider {
    public static COLORS = array('1' => 'red', '2' => 'green', ...);

    public function getColors() {
        return self::COLORS;
    }
}
```

Then, where you have stack of yout params:

```
$a = array(
  'attr_value1' => new FirstScheme(),
  'attr_value2' => new SecondScheme(),
);
```

You can call:

```
$param = 'attr_value1';

if(!isset($a[$param]))
    throw new Exception("undefined param");

if(!($a[$param] instanceof ColorsProvider))
    throw new Exception("Param should point to ColorsProvider");

$a[$param]->getColors();
```

---

Please note that it is full-objective. In PHP there are simplier ways to get this effects, but my solution is just elegant.

---

The another point is the interface *completely separates the source* of colors. There would be from file, database, xml, hardcoded etc.

---

Default implementation might be:

```
abstract class DefaultColorsProviderImpl implements ColorsProvider             {
    protected static COLORS = array();

    public function getColors() {
        return self::COLORS;
    }
}

class FirstScheme extends DefaultColorsProviderImpl {
    protected static COLORS = array( ... );
}
```

But still allows to make generic implementation that returns colors from e.x. from file.

Comment: `getColors()` implementation might (must?) be moved to a parent abstract class. And color property doesn't need to be either public or static

Comment: might be, but this solution (using interfaces) allows you to get colors from any source, ot only hardcoded array (as i mentioned). The another way is make default implementation (`ColorsProviderArrayImpl`) that returns colors from array (and it is popular solution, what you have mentioned, but still based on interfaces that allows you to create completely different implementation).

Comment: I still don't see any reason for code duplication (they still implement the same interface) or for leaving `$COLORS` property public and static (as long as you've decided to retrieve it using method, not directly)

Comment: Consider:

`abstract class DefaultColorsProviderImpl implements ColorsProvider             {
    proteted static COLORS = array();

    public function getColors() {
        return self::COLORS;
    }
}`

`class FirstScheme extends DefaultColorsProviderImpl {
    proteted static COLORS = array( ... );
}`

Here is no redundant code.

Comment: @Athlan The reason why I wanted it to be static is that more than one attribute can (and will) map to the same scheme. Using your example I would have to instantiate same schemes many times for different attribute values, which I consider not good.

Comment: The solution is use singleton or static method that will return static field.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to hard-coding the colors in their own classes would be the following approach:

```
class ColorScheme {

   protected $colors;

   public function __construct(array $colors) {
       $this->colors = $colors;
   }

   public function getColors() {
       return $this->colors;
   }

}

$scheme1 = new ColorScheme(array('red', 'blue', 'green'));
$scheme2 = new ColorScheme(array('yellow', 'pink', 'cyan'));
```

The equivalent for a python dictionary in PHP is an associative array. So you could do this:

```
$d = array (
    'values_1' => $scheme1->getColors(),
    'values_2' => $scheme2->getColors()
);
```

Comment: I still don't understand the part how I would get the mappings in run-time.

Comment: `$mapping = $scheme1->getColors();` Or what do you mean with `mapping` ?

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain differently. I have coloring schemes, like a few of them. They are known in advance. And they in run-time I have incoming objects, which possesses an attribute, that allows to find out the scheme I need to apply to it. That's why I put {'attr_value1': FirstScheme, ...} in my question.

Comment: It doesn't explain anything actually.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Why not just posting a code example that does not work for you?

Comment: @dragoon: are you sure we're not solving the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at the moment?

Comment: Ok, I give up, will accept Athlan's solution because he got the problem right.

Comment: @dragoon: actually there is no principal difference in solutions.

Comment: @zerkms He showed how to get the scheme based on the $param and told about singleton solution. Again, in my opinion, schemes should not be instantiated for each object or for each attribute, because there are only a few different schemes which I need to define manually somehow.

Comment: @dragoon: right, but it doesn't explain why they should be **static**. Any good reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can:

```
$schemes = [
  'attr_value1' => FirstScheme::$COLORS,
  'attr_value2' => SecondScheme::$COLORS,
  ...
];
```

Or even at runtime:

```
$schemes = [
  'attr_value1' => 'FirstScheme',
  'attr_value2' => 'SecondScheme',
  ...
];
```

And then:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($schemes['attr_value1']);
$schema = $reflector->getStaticPropertyValue('COLORS');
```

But this seems not any maintainable at all, and you would like to store such informations in a proper data layer, without hardcoding them as static fields of a class [which is not their purpose].